# How to print a tensor without showing gradients

Tags: python, pytorch

If I do something like this:

```
tmp = torch.ones(3, 2, 2, requires_grad=True)
out = tmp ** 2
print("\n{}".format(out))
```

I get as an output:

```
tensor([[[1., 1.],
         [1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1.],
         [1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1.],
         [1., 1.]]], grad_fn=<PowBackward0>)
```

I would like to print out just the values, not the grad_fn part.

However, doing

```
print("\n{}".format(out[0]))
```

results in:

```
tensor([[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
```

The only way I know is to `out.detach()` or there is another/better way? Just to clarify, I am happy the gradient is calculated. I just want to show the vector values without additional data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `data` should do the job for you:

```
tmp = torch.ones(3, 2, 2, requires_grad=True)
out = tmp ** 2
print("\n{}".format(out.data))
```

**Output:**

```
tensor([[[1., 1.],
         [1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1.],
         [1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1.],
         [1., 1.]]])
```